# Deleting fields in a MatLab structure with python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm trying to delete fields in a Matlab struct after loading it to python with `sio.loadmat()`,
I guess the solution would be delete the relevant fields in the numpy structured array that represents the mat file but I'm struggling with that.

How can I delete the fields in the np structured array, or delete them in other way from the .mat file using python.

Comment: One way or other you'll need to make a new array without that one field.  And then write a new .mat file.  Read the main structured array documentation page.

Comment: You'll probably need to be more specific and include example code/mat file. What exctly are you struggling with? It looks like `loadmat` creates a dictionary, so you could just use `d=sio.loadmat("file.mat")` and then `d.pop("variablename")` before saving again with `sio.savemat("new.mat", d)`

Comment: You can delete some objects in MATLAB by attributing them to `[]`, but you need to provide more details, your question is too vague. How is your data structured? Can you provide a sample program?

Comment: @Ed, that top level dict references the variables that were saved.  I think the OP wants to modify one of those variables, which was a MATLAB struct.  `loadmat` loads that as a numpy structured array.  He wants to remove one of its fields.

Comment: @hpaulj, you are right, but the OP should be motivated to provide some more info on the question, including a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), right?

Comment: `numpy.lib.recfunctions.drop_fields`.  Without a [mcve] I'll leave the rest to you.